# Ruby on Jets issue while deploy

Tags: node.js, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubyonjets

So I started to play with [Ruby on Jets](https://rubyonjets.com/quick-start/), a relatively new serverless framework for ruby and `AWS`, everything worked good on my local env, but once I started to deploy, I received an error on CloudFormation because the `nodejs` , version that jets is pushing by default was deprecated recently (I am using the polymorphic feature which allows you to have node and python functions too), so the question:

Is there a way to specify a version for the (runtime version) lambda function while deploying?

Answer (score 1):

looks like Ruby on Jets is dead :(

Comment: I explored it for some time. Didn't like it. As usual bad documentation. IMHO the scenario of mapping each action onto a AWS lambda function is not always an a good solutions, even not necessary in majority cases. So, using lambda functions in this case is an unnecessary complexity (install a simple hello-world and see what it creates on AWS: nested stacks, roles, .....). Jets is simply unnecessary layer between Ruby and AWS SAM. The only reason I'd use base my Web app on lambda functions is autoscaling though there are other options (maybe more convenient) to reach the scalability.